# How to add 1 to a JavaScript variable without it decreasing it's original number?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to increment 1 variable without it decreasing anything from the original number. Say for example that I started with 10 instead of 0, how do I let it go to 11 instead of resetting.

**Example:**

```html
<div class="game-object">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var clicks = 0;

    function updateClickCount() {
      document.getElementById("clickCount").innerHTML = clicks;
    }
  </script>
  <button type="button" onClick="clicks++;updateClickCount();" id="push">NO.</button>
  <div id="clickCount"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `clicks++` should do the trick. It's global, it shouldn't be reset. Unless you mean it gets reset when you reload the page.

Comment: Nothing resets, when you click the button. It just increases the number.

Comment: So basically you want to restore variable last value after page reloading and continue from that point? Or you're having trouble with adding 1 itself and it doesn't work (but I guess it should)?

Comment: Be more clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use localstorage to store the last click count , and it will persist on page reload as well.

try this.

```
<header>
    <strong>
              Don't Touch The Button
            </strong>
</header>
<div class="game-object">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let localData = localStorage.getItem('clicks');
        var clicks = 0;
        if (localData) clicks = Number(localData)

        function updateClickCount() {
            clicks++;
            localStorage.setItem('clicks', clicks);
            document.getElementById("clickCount").innerHTML = clicks;
        }
    </script>
    <button type="button" onClick="updateClickCount();" id="push">NO.</button>
    <div id="clickCount"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `localData` is a `string`, you should probably convert it to a `number` because this will fail if you use something like `clicks = clicks + 1` instead of `clicks++`.

Comment: Made the required changes, Thanks.

Comment: This also works: `var clicks = +localStorage.getItem('clicks') || 0;`